# Temporarily cant scroll website in firefox

Tags: firefox, scroll, mousewheel

I'm having trouble with this website on OSX firefox: http://yesopenwp.staging.wpengine.com

Typically (although not always) as the page loads, there's a moment (usually just a second or 2) when you can't scroll down using a mouse wheel. After a few seconds the problem seems to fix itself and you can scroll freely.

Scrolling down with keys in fine. And it seems when you scroll with keys, and then try to use a mouse scroll wheel you encounter the problem again.

Any ideas whats happening?

Comment: I discovered that it was the overflow-x: hidden; style in the .off-canvas-wrapper class that was messing with scrolling in Firefox. I've disabled the style on desktop and only applied it to smaller screens as it only used to control the off canvas menu on mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it was the overflow-x: hidden; style in the .off-canvas-wrapper class that was messing with scrolling in Firefox.

I've disabled the style on desktop and only applied it to smaller screens as it only used to control the off canvas menu on mobile devices